# Is it possible to include file content in a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I need to create or overwrite files on remote hosts. The modules `lineinfile` or `blockinfile` are useful when updating files, but not to create ones from scratch or completely overwrite existing ones.

The obvious solution is to use `copy` but I would like to have as much as possible a standalone playbook, without files on the side. **Is it possible to include in a playbook the content of the file to create?**

Maybe something along the lines of having a variable with the content of the file which can be used as the `src=`parameter for `copy` (I tried this but it does not work as `src` expects a local file)

Comment: blockinfile and lineinfile both have a parameter called "create" which you can set to yes to create a file from scratch. If you want to always overwrite the contents, and you do not want to use COPY, you can have two tasks: the first task will check if the file exists and remove it, the second task would use the lineinfile/blockinfile module with create set to yes and content set to whatever you want.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Copy with content:

```
  tasks:
    - copy:
        content: |
                 This is some
                 not too complex
                 cotent for a file
        dest: content.txt
```

But as per [Ansible doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html):

> This is for simple values, for anything complex or with formatting please switch to the template module.

Comment: We do this today and it works very nicely.  We build out our _odbc files from it.

Answer (score 5):

The [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) - module is a good way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you, but this module still requires external files, right? I did not see how the content could be included in the playbook (?)

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the module uses an extra file, the template, which is much more handy, if you use your task on several machines and the file in question has to be adjusted. Another use case is, if you have to run the task more than once.

Comment: The point of my question was to have a standalone playbook, without files aside (otherwise, as I mentioned in the question, I would have used `copy`).  @konstatin's solution covers that point.